# Shiny Tutorial Error in R

Tags: r, shiny

I've seen some cool uses of shiny with R to make web applications and wanted to try to learn how to use it myself. I am doing the tutorial right now, but when I get to the Inputs and Outputs part of the tutorial (http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#inputs-and-outputs) I run in to a problem.

Specifically, I am getting an error that says:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
>   Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that   can only be done from inside a reactive function.)

I've tried a bunch of different things and searched everywhere online but can't figure out what the problem is. I am running R version 2.15.2 on OS X Version 10.8.3. My default browser is Chrome.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with a reproducible example (i.e. code and example data), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for details.

Comment: I really recommend updating to R 3.0.1.

Answer (score 63):

I know this question is a bit dated, but responding for those who might come searching when faced with the same error message.

Since you haven't included your code, let's look at why this error message happens in general.

When the error message says "**Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.**" what it is saying is that you are accessing a "reactive" element inside the `ShinyServer` function, but *outside* any of the reactive functions such as `renderTable` or `renderPlot()` etc.

#### This won't work inside ShinyServer()

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    abc <- input$some.input.option   

  #other reactives here

})
```

#### Fix: Wrap it inside a `reactive`

This will work:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  abc <- reactive({
   abc <- input$some.input.option    
  })

  #other reactives here

})
```

And now, from inside the ShinyServer function, you can access that Input parameter by calling `abc()`
Note the parenthesis since it is a reactive function.

Comment: Thanks, this helps, but can you define "reactive element"?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you've repeated the use of the name `abc`?

Comment: @MichaelChirico (and anyone else wondering): The name `abc` is repeated simply for clarity's sake. The reactive object `abc()`, accessible throughout the server function, contains the same data as object `abc` within the `reactive({})` function. Giving both the same name makes that visually immediately clear.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I had this issue when I forgot about using `renderPrint`, which is easy to forget when you're just starting up.

For example:

```
shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  output$outputString <- input$something
  }
)
```

When what I really needed to do was

```
shinyServer(function(input,output) {
  output$outputString <- renderPrint({input$something})
  }
)
```

Comment: grat, but there're any better than `as.numeric(renderPrint({input$something}))`  if something is a numeric value?