# Apply multiple drop-down bottoms in Shiny-Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I want to use different drop-down bottoms in the shiny-dashboard to filter the data set, which is read by the first  drop-down field. The first drop-down bottom loops over all file names in the data-folder, loads and plots the data (it works well). 
In the next step, I want to apply ratings as a filter, which is chosen by another drop-down bottom. However, I get the following error,

```
if(dataRating =
                    ^
Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing C:\Temp\RtmpScI3tC\fileb32838a12cde
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error in sourceUTF8(serverR, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())) : 
  Error sourcing C:\Temp\RtmpScI3tC\fileb32838a12cde
```

My **Gui**:

```
library("shiny")

# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Default"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----

      selectInput(inputId = 'date',
                  label = 'Choose a date:',
                  choices = list.files(path = "C:/R_myfirstT/data",
                                       full.names = FALSE,
                                       recursive = FALSE)),
      # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----

      selectInput(inputId = 'rating',
                  label = 'Choose the rating:',
                  choices = c("All",0,1,2,3))
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)
```

and the **Server**:

```
 # Define server  ----
    server <- function(input, output) {

      #  Rating
      dataRating <- reactive({
        rating <- input$rating
        if (is.null(infile)){
          return(NULL)
        }

      })
      #
      dataset <- reactive({
        infile <- input$date
        if (is.null(infile)){
          return(NULL)
        }
        read.csv(paste0('C:/R_myfirstT/data',infile),header=TRUE, sep=";")
      })
    ###      OutPut
      if(dataRating ="All"){
        output$plot <- renderPlot({
        x <- dataset()$Marktwert
        hist(x, breaks = 40)
      })
    }
    }
```

The dashboard without `if` statement in `Server.R` looks like [image: this]

I would like to know,

*specialy*:

what did I do wrong in this case?

*generally*:

how can I apply different inputs from different drop-down bottoms with data.table operation as filters?

**Addendum**:
I changed the `if`-statement to `if(dataRating() =="All")` and

```
 dataRating <- reactive({
    rating <- input$rating
```

to

```
 dataRating <- reactive({
    dataRating  <- input$rating
```

I found a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002160/shiny-tutorial-error-in-r). However, I get another error

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
      Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

Sample data looks like:

```
  stand Rating  LGD  Marktwert   EL absolut 
6010    3   3   1142345261  1428757
6010    3   3   849738658   1028973
6010    1   3   1680222820  220554
6010    1   3   896459567   116673
6010    0   3   1126673222  72077
6010    1   3   704226037   93310
-   1   4   336164879   49299
6010    0   3   948607746   60443
6070    1   3   265014117   34170
6020    3   3   47661945    58551
6050    2   3   307011781   115959
6020    0   1   1064022992  20320
6010    0   3   831782040   52950
6080    3   3   19367641    20286
-   2   4   197857365   87608
6010    1   3   679828856   90884
6050    3   3   317092037   372362
6080    3   3   20223616    21929
6010    1   3   693736624   96899
6050    3   3   308447822   372915
6010    4   3   177281455   862068
```

Comment: I can't test this right now but `renderPlot({if (dataRating() == "All") ... })` should do the job for you.

Comment: @GregordeCillia: Applying your suggestion, I do not get any error. However, I do not obtain any Plot at all! Why actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to test taking a guess at the data. Please test this on your side:

**Update:** I edited slightly after sample data was added.

```
library("shiny")

# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Default"),

  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(

      # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----

      selectInput(inputId = 'date',
                  label = 'Choose a date:',
                  choices = list.files(path = "C:/R_myfirstT/data",
                                       full.names = FALSE,
                                       recursive = FALSE)),
      # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----

      selectInput(inputId = 'rating',
                  label = 'Choose the rating:',
                  choices = c("All",0,1,2,3))
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server  ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  #  Rating
  dataRating <- reactive({
    input$rating
  })
  #
  dataset <- reactive({
    infile <- input$date
    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(paste0('C:/R_myfirstT/data/',infile),header=TRUE, sep=";")
  })
  ###      OutPut
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if(dataRating() =="All"){  
      x <- dataset()$Marktwert
      hist(x, breaks = 40)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Some comments:**

"Error in : object 'infile' not found" is caused by this code block:

```
#  Rating
      dataRating <- reactive({
        rating <- input$rating
        if (is.null(infile)){
          return(NULL)
        }

      })
```

`infile` does not exist here. Remember in the `dataset` reactive you have `infile <- input$date` first.

Furthermore, in order to assign a value to `dataRating` you either need to put `input$rating` at the end of the `reactive` like I did or put `return(input$rating)`. You did similar when you placed `read.csv(paste0('C:/R_myfirstT/data',infile),header=TRUE, sep=";")` at the end of the `dataset` reactive code block.

Comment: you are totaly right with 'infile' I recognized by myself too, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please try my code above and let me know. It worked for me using your dataset, thanks.

Comment: wow true. It works very nice. However, It does not help me to achieve my intention. I am going to use: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/basic-datatable.html                                                                      In the case, that I have a question, how can I address it to you?

Comment: Keep using the comments here or add a new stackoverflow question

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have the data files to test myself but using Gregor's comment please try editing this code:

```
###      OutPut
  if(dataRating ="All"){
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
    x <- dataset()$Marktwert
    hist(x, breaks = 40)
  })
}
```

to:

```
###      OutPut
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if(dataRating() == "All"){
      x <- dataset()$Marktwert
      hist(x, breaks = 40)
    }
  })
```

**Notes:** You are correct that `dataRating` being a reactive value needs to be called using `dataRating()`. However you need to call this inside a reactive not outside as you currently have it (as the error message suggests). Furthermore you need `==` in this case. Your edit:

```
dataRating <- reactive({
    rating <- input$rating
```

to

```
dataRating <- reactive({
    dataRating  <- input$rating
```

should not be necessary.

Comment: Hi Eli, and thanks a lot and sorry for the late reaction. I tried your suggestion. However, I get "Error in <reactive:dataRating>: object 'infile' not found"

Comment: Can you give us a minimal reproducible example then to test?

Comment: you mean, you need  a small bunch of the data? Because the code is completely there!

Comment: Exactly! We have no way of testing your code without the appropriate data. Column names, types, etc. are vital. You can anonymise it if you want but we need some small dataset.

Comment: I added  a data-sample  in the origin question!